# Typescript error TS1005: ':' expected. with Object.assign()

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have nested `Object.assign()` in typescript:

```
(<any>Object).assign({}, state, {
    action.item_id: (<any>Object).assign({}, state[action.item_id], {
        label_value: action.value
    })
})
```

This yields those errors:

```
ERROR in ./src/reducers/ItemsReducer.ts
(2,19): error TS1005: ':' expected.

ERROR in ./src/reducers/ItemsReducer.ts
(2,26): error TS1005: ',' expected.

ERROR in ./src/reducers/ItemsReducer.ts
(2,28): error TS1136: Property assignment expected.
```

The weird thing is that the errors vanish if I fix the key e.g.:

```
(<any>Object).assign({}, state, {
    "fixed_key": (<any>Object).assign({}, state[action.item_id], {
        label_value: action.value
    })
})
```

This left me clueless, why isn't it ok to call `action.item_id` at that place when he doesn't complain few characters after?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using a variable as a property name in an object declaration, you need to use [computed property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) notation by putting it in brackets:

```
(<any>Object).assign({}, state, {
    [action.item_id]: (<any>Object).assign({}, state[action.item_id], {
        label_value: action.value
    })
})
```